# Start a counter from where left earlier

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where there is a counter and based on this counter I need to create rows in Excel.

Currently, This starts from `0`, every time I run this. Below is my code

```
int counter = 0;
        if (ext.contains("xls")) {
            int result = appendDataToExcel(file, workbook, rowCount, counter);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

private static int appendDataToExcel(File file, XSSFWorkbook workbook, int rowCount, int counter) throws Exception {
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int noOfRows = sheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        short lastCell;
        Cell cell;
        XSSFRow row;
        lastCell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            cell = row.createCell(lastCell);
            cell.setCellValue(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString());
            counter += 1;
        }
        wb.close();
        fin.close();
        return counter;
    }
```

Here the `result` is showing correct value, but how can I use the `result` as a parameter.

There are 10 rows to be created in first file, and 20 in second.

Here, currently, 10 rows are created and the next 20 are replacing the previous instead of appending.

I'm looking for a logic where in the counter gets updated with the `result` and in my `for-loop` I can use

```
for(int i= counter; i<rowCount;i++){
//My code
}
```

please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: How is the if under your `int counter = 0;` even called? What is the method surrounding it? How is called mulitple times? If you want to obtain the incremented counter from the return value just do `counter = appendDataToExcel` instead of creating a new int...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make the counter static:

```
static int counter = 0;
```

then in your loop

```
rowCount+=counter;
for(int i= counter; i<rowCount;i++){
//My code
}
```